# Python Program looking for nonexistent Version 2.7 Python framework in /Library.... but it IS in /System/Library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran a program and got the following error:

```
samples$ python Sample.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sample.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Leap, sys, thread, time
  File "/Users/mutt/Downloads/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_mac/LeapSDK/samples/Leap.py", line 28, in <module>
    LeapPython = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/mutt/Downloads/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_mac/LeapSDK/samples/Leap.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('LeapPython', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mutt/Downloads/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_mac/LeapSDK/samples/LeapPython.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/mutt/Downloads/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_mac/LeapSDK/samples/LeapPython.so
  Reason: image not found
```

In `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/`, there is a 3.4 version, but not 2.7, which is what the program wants. There is a 2.7 in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/`

This is an example file from the LeapMotion SDK

- Why isn't there a 2.7 version in the /Library/... folder?
- Should I install it differently somehow? I have already installed 3.4 and 2.7.11 with homebrew
- Should I make a symlink from the other folder?

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your problem is probably related to the `python` binary that you are using. For example, `which python` might return `/usr/bin/python`, which is the `/System/Library` python, and not the one you installed separately

Comment: Any suggestions about what to do? I have removed the Homebrew python, and the only ones left are the 2.7 and 3.4 that Apple put on there. 2.7 is linked from /System/Library... to /usr/bin and 3.4 is linked from /Library... to /usr/local/bin. So I am running python 2.7, but it still wants to go to the /Library folder where python3 is to find 2.7

Comment: Update: I made a symbolic link from /System/Library to /Library and it works now. There must be a better way, though. Why did this happen in the first place?

Comment: Not sure, but I also have python from homebrew, and I do not have a `/Library/Frameworks/Python` and everything works okay for me.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS create a Symlink as @Peter mentioned in comment:

sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework /Library/Frameworks